# How to find value of last cell in an Excel row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet with a delimited list of directories and files in rows with varying numbers of columns. I just want the filename value (e.g. 123-E-001.xls, situated in the last cell of each row) to be listed in column A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an Index/Match formula along these lines:

```
=INDEX(B1:ZZ1,MATCH("zzzz",B1:ZZ1,1))
```

The `Match("zzzz"...)` will find the last cell with text in the range and pass its number to the Index function.

It will be faster than the Lookup approach.

Comment: I wonder if it might be faster to use the COL of xllastcell rather than make it look all the way along? Or do you think it might be clever and stop anyway?

Comment: @Lefty, This is a worksheet formula, not VBA. Match() with a 1 as the last parameter will find the last populated cell almost immediately, because it does not look in cell after cell. It's certainly faster than passing things to VBA and back.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I was thinking in VBA for some reason. Forgive me. I like this Match, I've never used it but will have to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LOOKUP function. If you put the following formula in a cell A1, it will find the last non-blank value between B1 and XX1. Change the XX1 to a column that is expected to be to the right of the last data column

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(B1:XX1<>""),B1:XX1)
```

Note that you cannot have anywhere near as many rows as columns, so if you have lots of file names, you should use columns instead of rows. The following formula does the same for data in a column:

```
=INDEX(A:A, COUNTA(A:A), 1)
```

Comment: CountA will only work if there are no empty cells. Also, FWIW, Index can be used on rows, too, not just columns.

Comment: LOOKUP can also be used for a column of values, e.g. `=LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:A100<>""),A1:A100)`....or mimicking teylyn's INDEX/MATCH, `=LOOKUP("zzzz",A1:A100)`